# Can the HAProxy binary be upgraded without downtime?

Tags: haproxy

From my understanding it is possible to update the NGINX binary in place without losing connections, as shown [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-nginx-in-place-without-dropping-client-connections). Is it possible to do the same thing with HAProxy? A quick search didn’t seem to indicate yes, but perhaps I’m missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think that HAProxy provides any builtin solution for this. However, you can achieve somewhat similar like that is happening in the link mentioned, by virtue of linux `iptables`. The steps should be like this:

1. Route the traffic using iptable rules from the existing port to the currently running local port of haproxy.
2. Install the new binary in a separate folder different from where the existing binary is lying.
3. Start another haproxy process on a different port with same configs.
4. Reroute the traffic from the initial port to the new port. A guide on how to achieve this without any packet loss can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/828703/iptables-redirecting-established-connections).
5. If all works fine on the new port, stop the previous process otherwise you could revert back to the old process following step 4.

Comment: Oh, that makes a ton of sense. Thanks for the response! I don’t have enough reputation to accept that as an answer officially but this was enough for me!